# Google map api key for a domain

Tags: google-maps

I want to use Google Maps API. When I am getting the API key from Google, they are providing for a url, but my url is dynamic. How to fix that problem?

My url is like: https://evibe.in/ticket/{id}.

Comment: Please provide more information. What does *dynamic* mean in your case? What happens that the key is not working / error message?

Comment: My url is like - evibe.in/ticket/{id}. here my url is not fixed .It will differ for diffrent id

Comment: Then you could just use the star for whitespacing (as described in the developer console): https://evibe.in/ticket* or even https://evibe.in/*

Comment: thanks @mxlse. I am using google map api for the first time. Thanks for the help. It's working :)

Comment: Please check the error message in the JavaScript console next time, try to solve it with the documentation mentioned there and if you can't add this error message in your Stackoverflow post, so the others can help you better and we see what you've already done. The maps API is very well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *dynamic* URLs with a certain base path you could whitespace the URL (as described at the credentials page @developer console). Just go to the [Credentials Page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and type

`https://evibe.in/ticket/*`

as HTTP referrer. Now all URLs with this basepart are included - no matter what is coming after the star.